# How to return data from event call back to JS interop method in Blazor

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor

Am wrapping some existing JS plugins to blazor components. when doing so, i faced below issue.
i have a callback method, which has triggered from JS to blazor using dotnet reference -> `invokeMethodAsync`

this.dotnet.invokeMethodAsync("Trigger", this.eventName, '');

it's perfectly triggers the JSinvokable method. but here, i need to return the data from blazor source to JS function handler where it has been raised.

Instead invokeMethodAsync, tried invokeMethod, getting the below error

https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/JSInterop/Microsoft.JSInterop.JS/src/src/Microsoft.JSInterop.ts#L65

whether it is possible to return data from event call back to JS function from where it has been raised as synchronous action?

Edited:

C# side code

```
public class ExampleJsInterop
{
    private readonly IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;

    public ExampleJsInterop(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        _jsRuntime = jsRuntime;
    }

    public object CallHelloHelperSayHello(string name)
    {
        // sayHello is implemented in wwwroot/exampleJsInterop.js
        return _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>(
            "exampleJsFunctions.sayHello",
            new DotNetObjectRef(new HelloHelper(name)));
    }
}

public class HelloHelper
{
    public HelloHelper(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JSInvokable]
    public string SayHello()
    {
        return $"Hello, {Name}!";
    }
}
```

JS code:

```
window.exampleJsFunctions = {
showPrompt: function (text) {
    return prompt(text, 'Type your name here');
},
displayWelcome: function (welcomeMessage) {
    document.getElementById('welcome').innerText = welcomeMessage;
},
returnArrayAsyncJs: function () {
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('BlazorSample', 'ReturnArrayAsync')
        .then(data => {
            data.push(4);
            console.log(data);
        });
},
sayHello: function (dotnetHelper) {
    debugger;
    dotnetHelper.invokeMethod('SayHello')
        .then(r => {
            debugger;
            console.log(r);
        });

    console.log('function outside');
}
```

};

Razor code:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="@TriggerNetInstanceMethod">
    Trigger .NET instance method HelloHelper.SayHello
</button>

@functions {


public void TriggerNetInstanceMethod()
{

    var exampleJsInterop = new ExampleJsInterop(JSRuntime);
    exampleJsInterop.CallHelloHelperSayHello("Blazor");
}
}
```

Here HelloHelper class -> SayHello method is not triggered from JS to C# side when i particularly mapped via invokeMethod not invokeMethodAsync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer for this question to collect the data back through aync action.

JS Code:

```
sayHello: async function (dotnetHelper) {

    var promise = dotnetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('SayHello')
        .then(r => {
            debugger;
            console.log(r + "inside");
        });

    var result = await promise; // wait till the promise resolves (*)

    console.log('function outside');
}
```

in Js, used async function to resolve this issue

Answer (score 4):

**It's perfectly triggers the JSinvokable method. but here, i need to return the data from blazor source to JS function handler where it has been raised.**

Can I rephrase your statement thus:

> The JSinvokable method is called, but I can't return a value to the JS
>   method.

Right ?

You can follow this code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="exampleJsFunctions.returnArrayAsyncJs()">
    Trigger .NET static method ReturnArrayAsync
</button>

@functions {
    [JSInvokable]
    public static Task<int[]> ReturnArrayAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
    }
}


And this:




 window.exampleJsFunctions = {
  returnArrayAsyncJs: function () {
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('BlazorSample', 'ReturnArrayAsync').then(data => {
      data.push(4);
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
};
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks Issac. Given solution works for async methods, is it possible to do synchronous action?

Comment: I think not...However, the Blazor team recommend to use asynchronous coding whenever possible, even if synchronicity is supported, though JavaScript and WebAssembly share the same UI thread, asynchronous programming  is viable and supported, but you can't get parallel or concurrent programming.

Comment: Thanks Issac, i have updated the query, could you please check and give me idea if possible